# Updating a property in a struct inside an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct

In my app I download a load of JSON.

I then store that as an array of structs and use that to populate a `UITableView`.

One of the properties of the struct is an `NSURL` for an image. Another property is an optional `UIImage`.

The struct has a mutating function `downloadImage` which uses the URL to download the image and store it in its property.

Like this...

```
struct SearchItem {
    // other properties...
    let iconURL: NSURL
    var icon: UIImage?

    mutating func downloadImage() -> Task<UIImage> {
        let tsc = TaskCompletionSource<UIImage>()

        NSURLSession.sharedSession().downloadTaskWithURL(iconURL) {
            (location, response, error) in
            if let location = location,
                data = NSData(contentsOfURL: location),
                image = UIImage(data: data) {
                self.icon = image
                tsc.setResult(image)
                return
            }

            tsc.setError(NSError(domain: "", code: 1, userInfo: nil))
        }.resume()

        return tsc.task
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is this. (and I have been stumped by this in the past).

I have an array `[SearchItem]` that I use to populate the tableview.

In `cellForRow` I have the code... `if let searchItem = items[indexPath.row]...`

It then checks if the image is nil and downloads...

```
if let image = searchItem.icon {
    cell.imageView.image = image
} else {
    searchItem.downloadImage().continueOnSuccessWith(Executor.MainThread) {
        _ in
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
    }
}
```

But this never goes through to put the image into the cell. This is because the `SearchItem` is struct and so `pass-by-value`. So the search item that I am downloading the image for is not the same `SearchItem` as the one stored in the array.

How can I ensure that the image that is downloaded is then stored into the `SearchItem` inside the actual array?

Comment: Simple: use classes  :D

Comment: @jrturton but but... Is this not an ideal use case for structs?

Comment: evidently not, otherwise it would be working

Comment: @jrturton So then... what the hell are structs for if I have to rule them out any time I want to store data in an array?

Comment: The classic: You cannot return something from a function/method which contains an asynchronous task. You need a – also asynchronous – completion handler

Comment: @vadian really, no. Look at the code. That is what I'm doing. Have a look at the `Bolts Swift` framework.

Comment: @jrturton srsly though. Is that the solution here? If so then I cannot see how people have been raving about using structs and pass-by-value data etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use classes.

You're getting a copy of `searchItem` in your `cellForRow` method. Whatever you do to this, will be done only to that copy. What you actually want is for the changes you make to that copy to be applied to the version in the array.

Therefore you want reference semantics, therefore use classes.

You could dance around re-inserting the updated copy into the original array if you liked, but what does that gain you besides a line of extra code and probably some other problems.

Comment: Seems you're right. "Struct, I am disappoint." As a side question/comment, the more I write Swift the more useless structs seem. Is there any use case for them that doesn't suffer from the same problems as this? To be honest, the more I write Swift, the more I dislike it and think I may as well go back to Objective-C. :(

Comment: You could just update the struct in the array to you "new" struct (after mutation)

Comment: @AMomchilov that's what I say in the last line of the answer

Comment: @jrturton Yeah just adding that for emphasis: what he wants to do is possible, but it works in a different way.

Answer (score 3):

Structs are lightweight data objects that are not passed by reference, but instead copies itself as needed when you a) pass it to a new function, b) try and access it in a block. Arrays in Swift also work slightly differently than their Obj-C counterparts. When you have an Array of class objects the array will be a reference type, and you'll be able to achieve what you're trying to achieve here. But on the other hand if the Array is of Structs the array looses its reference semantics and uses copy-by-value instead.

This difference is really powerful when used appropriately, you can greatly optimise your code, make it run faster, have less errors produced by mutable object references having changes happen in multiple parts of your code, etc. But it's up to you as a developer to see where the gains of these optimisations are useful or where it makes sense to use objects instead.

Comment: Thanks. The problem I have is that any online references that are non-trivial seem to disagree with at least one other reference. Trying to follow them leads to occasions like this. For instance, a particular article says to use structs for `Person Data`. But then if you need to change the name of that person you will be changing a copy of the original so it seems like that is the wrong use for struct. I honestly can't see any use for them beyond super trivial input parameters. But then I could use a tuple for something like that?! Would love a good website if you can recommend one? Thans

Comment: I can recommend these two WWDC 2015 Apple dev videos: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/414/ - https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/

Comment: @Fogmeister The benefit of value types is that they allow for safe mutation. Whenever you call a library method and pass in your struct, you can be sure that your struct will be unaffected, and that no unexpected side effects will occur. Additionally, this minimized sharing means that you don't have to worry about synchronization in multi-threaded applications.

Comment: @Fogmeister The most important flaw of reference semantics is that it subtly introduces opportunities for unexpected data sharing. Many times, it's unintended. Value types minimize the impact of state, and make a program (generally) more easy to reason about. You never have to think about (what other places reference this object?)

Comment: @AMomchilov so really the only proper use case for a struct is when running a function. For instance when "uploading a new message" your message might be a class but you could create an input parameter as a struct and pass that in to avoid mutation while the message is queued etc... ?

Comment: @DannyBravo I have watched those several times. :) Thermostats and ovens and houses etc...

Comment: @Fogmeister No, not at all, we should continue this in chat